# Call a java function in .jsp when answering a form

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have a .jsp file of a basic chat with a bot, the page is designed as a div that should hold the messages that outcome or income from a form.
The form has one input line that should hold the message.

I want to call a java function that's in a different .java file from the div only after the form is submited

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b>
         <%
                if (ctx.isLoggedIn()) //if there is someone in the current session
                {
                    String name = ctx.getName(); // puts the name in the page
                    out.write(name); // same as last row
                }
        %></b></p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit Chat</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="chatbox" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
    <%
        //the place I want to call the function
     %>
    </div>

    <form name="message" action="#" method="post">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" oninput="buttonEnabled()"/>
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg"/>
    </form> <!-- the form that is served -->
</div>
```

`ctx` is defined as an object from a class I created

```
Context ctx = new Context(pageContext);
```

I tried to call the function like this-

```
<%
if(request.getParameter("usermsg").toString().length() > 0)// not empty
    out.write(ctx.handleMessages());
%>
```

but It didn't work for some reason.

the function `handleMessages()` has a queue that contains all of the messages from the server and from the client and returns a `String` that is already build as an `HTML` code-

```
returnedMsg += "<b>"+message.getUser()+"</b> - <a style='color:gray;'>"+message.getTime()+"</a>";
        returnedMsg += "<br>";
        returnedMsg += "<a>"+msg.getText()+"</a>";
        returnedMsg += "<hr>";
```

So every chat message should look like that-

[image: how the chat should look]

It would really help me if someone knows how to call `handleMessages()` from that div when the form is submited.

Thank's ahead.

Comment: Where is your `handleMessages` function? Your code is on seperate part, it's hard to understand what are you doing!

Comment: I don't think it's really necessary to see the function, the important thing is that it returns the HTML chat style.
I just need to know how and when to call it.